# Questionable proof of Liouville's Theorem (number theory)

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-explanation, transcendental-numbers

I saw a proof of Liouville's theorem on ProofWiki. It goes like this:

Let $x$ be a Liouville number. Also suppose that it is an algebraic number.

Liouville numbers are irrational, so there exists $c > 0$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}_{>0}$ such that:

$$\left | x - \frac{p}{q} \right | \geq \frac{c}{q^{n}}$$

for every pair $p, q \in \mathbb{Z}$ with $q \neq 0$. Let $r \in \mathbb{N}_{>0}$ such that $2^{r} \geq \frac{1}{c}$. Since $x$ is a Liouville number, there exists $p, q \in \mathbb{Z}$ with $q > 1$ such that:
$$ \left | x - \frac{p}{q} \right | < \frac{1}{q^{n+r}} \leq \frac{1}{2^{r} q^{n}} \leq \frac{c}{q^{n}}$$
which is a contradiction. Thus $x$ is transcendental. $\blacksquare$

This proof has 2 problems: this is not a contradiction (case where $\left | x - \frac{p}{q}\right | = \frac{c}{q^{n}}$) and there is no use of that $x$ is algebraic. The first problem could be solved like this:

$$\left | x - \frac{p}{q} \right | = \frac{c}{q^{n}} \Rightarrow \left | x q^{n} - p q^{n-1} \right | = c$$
which is false for sufficiently small $c$ (because $x$, $p$, $q$ are not said to be dependent on $c$). But the second problem still is present. How this "proof" could be correct? Is it just plain wrong?

Comment: By the properties of Liouville numbers, you can pick $m>n$ and find $p,q$ such that $|x-p/q|<1/q^m<c/q^n$, which contradicts the fact that $x$ is algebraic.

Comment: @TravorLZH how exactly is this contradicting fact of being algebraic?

Comment: This is more correctly done online

Comment: @Bemciu If $x$ is algebraic, you just cannot find $p,q$ to make $|x-p/q|<c/q^n$.

Comment: @TravorLZH could you prove it in answers, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x$ is some algebraic number, then there is come $c>0$ and $n\in\mathbb N$ such that

$$
\left|x-\frac pq\right|\ge{c\over q^n}.\tag1
$$

for all coprime integers $p,q$ such that $x\ne p/q$.

However, it follows from the definition of Liouville number that for all $m\in\mathbb N$ there exists infinitely many pairs of coprime $p,q$ such that

$$
0<\left|x-\frac pq\right|<{1\over q^m}.
$$

If $m$ is large enough such that $q^{-m}<cq^{-n}$. Then, we see that (1) is violated, which indicates that $x$ cannot be algebraic.

### Proof of (1)

Since $x$ is algebraic, it must be a root of some polynomial $P(t)$ with integer coefficients:

$$
P(t)=a_nt^n+a_{n-1}t^{n-1}+\dots+a_0.
$$

Because $p$ has finitely many roots, we can find some $k>0$ such that $p(t)\ne0$ whenever $0<|t-x|<k$. Let $M$ be the maximum of $P'(t)$ in $[x-k,x+k]$, so it follows from the mean value theorem that $\exists c\in(x-k,x+k)$ such that

$$
|P(t)|=|t-x|\cdot|p'(c)|\le M|t-x|\tag2
$$

When $t=p/q$ and $0<|x-t|<k$. By the properties of integers, we know

$$
q^n|P(t)|=|a_np^n+a_{n-1}p^{n-1}q+\dots+a_0q^n|\ge1.\tag3
$$

Combining (2) and (3), we get

$$
\left|x-\frac pq\right|\ge{|P(p/q)\over M}\ge{M^{-1}\over q^n}.
$$

Comment: But what about rational algebraic numbers? The equation 1 is then false

Comment: The validity of (1) is not affected by whether $x$ is rational or not.

Comment: But it is interesting and important to show that inequality $(1)$ is implied by being algebraic, this answer is incomplete

Comment: @FShrike I just added the proof of (1)